Best Practices for RaaS Platform Development Using ROS 2
I am developing a Robot-as-a-Service (RaaS) platform with ROS 2, where users can manage their purchased or rented robots. The platform will include user-specific apps and a superadmin role for comprehensive monitoring and diagnostics.
Could you share best practices for the following aspects in a ROS 2-based system?

User and Robot Management: How should we manage user accounts and
robot identification in a single ROS 2 ecosystem?
Robot Registration: What's the best approach for users to dynamically
register new robots to their accounts?
Monitoring and Diagnostics: Recommendations for integrating real-time
robot monitoring into user apps?
Superadmin Functionality: How to implement features for broader
control and oversight by engineers or company owners?

I'm particularly interested in how to handle multiple users and robots securely and efficiently.
